# What should image size in px be for A0 with a Canon iPF8300

Tags: print-design, dpi

I am producing an A0 poster. I have been told that the printer is a [Canon iPF8300](http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Work/Products/Professional_Print/Large_Format/iPF8300/#p-specification1).

The spec says;

> Maximum Print Resolution 2,400 x 1,200 dpi
>
> Nozzle Pitch  1200 dpi x 2

I'm not sure what these numbers mean. i.e why the max print ratio is 2:1, I thought that it would be square like he nozzle pitch.

Would I be right in thinking that it would be 39732px x 56184px for A0 (33.11 x 46.82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just print at 300ppi, so if it is 33.11 inches wide, 33.11 x 300 = 9933px, 46.82 tall, 46.82 x 300 = 14046px.

You should supply an image at 9933px x 14046px (not taking into account bleed/trim)

Comment: Thank you John, how did you calculate 300ppi? or is that the limit of human vision?

Comment: You're welcome. 300 is industry standard for print.